# What to do when vim syntax folding fails altogether?

Tags: python, vim, spf13vim

I had folding just stop working in my Python sources... without a rhyme or reason.  The fix was't immediately obvious and I did not find an answer on SO...  I'm using spf13vim and I have tried `set foldmethod=indent` six ways to Sunday and no dice... I have nothing else futzing with folding in my .vimrc.local and I have already tried updating spf13vim although the problem just started willy nilly while I was coding after writing my buffer to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When folding (or anything) goes awry in VIM, whether you have spf13vim or any other elaborate .vimrc mod, begin with this...

`rm ~/.vimviews/*`

...and restart vim.  It cleared this problem up with magic.  I hope this helps someone stay young.

Comment: That `~/.vimviews` is non-standard, and presumably comes from spf13. Let romainl tell you why Vim distributions are prone to cause such grief.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I decided to not care anymore.

Comment: @romainl apocalypse now?

Comment: @romainl Your rants will be missed; I hope you'll channel your energy to more worthwhile advocacy ;-)